# NPM INSTALL does not recreates .js files from .ts files

Tags: node.js, angular, tsconfig

I am trying to compile my angular2/typescript files to javascript files.

*"npm install"* (without any warnings or errors)

creates node_modules, but not recreates .js files form my .ts files and angular modules does not updates.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "files": [
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "scripts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "react-super-components": "^0.3.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "param-store":"^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

after NPM START there is

```
1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:05:50 404 POST /api/logging
```

in log and it's never ends.

What can i check?

Comment: To compile command is  npm run tsc . To compiler in watch mode command is    npm run tsc:w  . In watch mode compiler will automatically compile all  your ts file as soon as your save any file.

Answer (score 1):

npm install will just install the mentioned packages in package.json file.

to generate `js` code you need to run

`npm start`

which will run typescript compiler in watch mode and will transpile `ts` code to `js` code.

look here what `npm start` command does:

```
start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` will install the packages listed in package.json

If the typings folder doesn't show up after running npm install, you'll need to install it manually with the command:

```
npm run typings install
```

You need to run `npm start`

This command runs the following two parallel node processes:

1. The TypeScript compiler in watch mode which will take of transpiling from typescript to javascript.
2. A static file server called lite-server that loads index.html in a browser and refreshes the browser when application files change.

Comment: Sorry i fogot to mention that i am using npm start after instal. There is some strange in log:[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
[1] 16.09.23 14:02:28 404 POST /api/logging
... ...   ... and never ends